# I Cannot Connect my Expo App to localhost Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am building a react native app using expo and I am trying to connect to a `http://localhost/api` running on my localhost. All I ma getting is network error.

The expo app is running on a real device. I did that using `expo start --localhost --android`

I have tried using the ip address provided by the `ipconfig /all` instead of localhost but I am still getting `Network Error`

Here is my code

```
  const fetchApi = async () => {
try {
  const res = await axios.get("http://10.2.0.56:8000/");
  console.log(res.data);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

};

Somebody please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)